# cordova-plugin-purchase 定期購読のアップグレードで前回購入分が解約されない

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

Monacaでcordova-plugin-purchaseにてios、Androidのアプリ内課金の定期購読を開発中です。
iosはつつがなく完了しましたが、AndroidのGoogle Play Billing Library 対応のstore.orderが思ったように動作せず、前回購入したプロダクトが解約されず、二重購入になります。
なお、二重購入は端末の購入履歴で確認しています。
クローズテストなので7回自動更新され、最後に自動解約されます。

●知りたいことは、cordova-plugin-purchaseでのstore.order(product, additionalData)の記述方法です。
下記のレスポンスなどを見ると、additionalData部分が反映されていない気がします。
記述サンプルも見つけられないので地味に実験していますが、ウダツが上がりません。

購入ボタンを押すと下記が動作します。
store.order(アップグレードproduct_id, { oldSku: 前回のproduct_id, prorationMode: 'DEFERRED' });
または
store.order(アップグレードproduct_id, 'DEFERRED');

参照
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/api.md の store.order()
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/releases のv10.3.0

●cordova-plugin-purchaseからのレスポンス
・・・・
downloading"":false,""downloaded"":false,""additionalData"":null,""transaction"":{""type"":""android-playstore"",""id"":""GPA.
・・・・
＝＞additionalDataがnull？？なんか入りそうな気がしますが。。。。
＝＞マニュアルにはこのような書き方です。
product.additionalData - additional data possibly required for product purchase

●Google Play Developer API へ渡すデータ
{""orderId"":""GPAxxxxxxx"",""packageName"":""xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",""productId"":""プロダクト"",""purchaseTime"":xxxxxxxxxx,""purchaseState"":0,""purchaseToken"":""トークン"",""autoRenewing"":true,""acknowledged"":true}

●Google Play Developer API - Purchases.subscriptionsからのレスポンス（レシート検証後）
{""startTimeMillis"":""xxxxxx"",""expiryTimeMillis"":""xxxxx"",""autoRenewing"":true,""priceCurrencyCode"":""JPY"",""priceAmountMicros"":""10000000000"",""countryCode"":""JP"",""developerPayload"":"""",""paymentState"":1,""orderId"":""GPA.xxxxxxxxxx"",""purchaseType"":0,""acknowledgementState"":1,""kind"":""androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase""}

●環境
ビルド環境　Android 9.1.0
Cordovaバージョン　10.0.0
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase バージョン　最新版
デバッグビルドを端末にインストールしてテスト中。

よろしくお願い致します！！

Comment: 実験進展

●cordova-plugin-purchaseからのレスポンス

additionalDataにデータが設定されました。

,""additionalData"":{""oldSku"":""gminipoint100"",""prorationMode"":""DEFERRED"",""applicationUsername"":""""},""transaction""

●Google Play Developer API - Purchases.subscriptionsからのレスポンス

{""startTimeMillis"":""xxx"",""expiryTimeMillis"":""xxx"",""autoRenewing"":true,""priceCurrencyCode"":""JPY"",""priceAmountMicros"":""1000000000"",""countryCode"":""JP"",""developerPayload"":"""",""paymentState"":1,""orderId"":""xx"",""purchaseType"":0,""acknowledgementState"":0,""kind"":""androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase""}

Comment: googleからのレスポンスにlinkedPurchaseTokenが入るような気がしますが。。。。。相変わらず、二重購入になってしまいます。

Comment: ●google play での何か設定が必要なのでしょうか？